# Como puedo ejecutar este codigo que esta en un .sh

Tags: linux, xml

Quisiera aplicarle a un archivo **.xml** lo que viene dentro de este **.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -p -i -e "s[- <][-      <]g" $1
perl -p -i -e "s[>    ][>      - ]g"  $1
perl -p -i -e "s[,][]g"  $1
perl -p -i -e "s[<Concepto></Concepto>][<Concepto>SUSCRIPCION</Concepto>]g"  $1
perl -p -i -e "s[>   -][>      -]g"  $1
sed -i 's/|//g' $1
sed -i 's/*//g' $1
```

Como podria realizar esto?

Comment: Podrias reformular la pregunta, creo que no nos ha quedado claro que es lo que quieres conseguir

Answer (score 0):

Podrías redirigir la salida del archivo desde la consolal de esta forma:

```
./archivo.sh parametro1 > archivo.xml
```

Comment: Porque me confundí jaja, ahi lo corregí. Gracias!